# use email id for account creation woocomerce

Tags: woocommerce, checkout, account

I want user to get registered with email id and password in woocommerce checkout. Can anyone tell me how to achieve this? I have moved account creation field above billing form[image]

Please help me on how to use email id in place of username?

Answer (score 0):

There is an option in WooCommerce to achieve your requirement. Follow the steps below.

- Goto WooCommerce -> Settings -> Accounts & Privacy
- Scroll to Account creation section
- Click on the checkbox with label **Allow customers to create an account during checkout**
- Click Save

Now you can see in checkout you can see a checkbox with label **Create an account?**. On clicking that you will see username and password inputs

[image: See the Screenshot]